# Android - Design Library parallax header

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-design-library

I am having trouble coming up with an XML layout to achieve a desired effect.

1. The toolbar should remain pinned at the top at all times. (Green rectangle)
2. The parallax region (Red rectangle), should have a parallax scroll effect when the recyclerview is scrolled (indicated by the up/down arrows in red).

[image: Picture example of my XML layout]

This is what my current XML layout looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="This is a test widget" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="This is a test widget" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="This is a test widget" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="This is a test widget" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="This is a test widget" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My XML layout completely scrolls the content up and out of the window & upon return (scroll down) it pulls down about 56dp worth of the appbarlayout (the size of my toolbar), then after some more scrolling the rest comes down with it.

How can achieve 1 & 2?

-----  EDIT: I modified my XML layout to the following.  -----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="This is a test widget" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="This is a test widget" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="This is a test widget" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="This is a test widget" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="This is a test widget" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It works for the most part, but the views inside the parallax section are overlaying the toolbar.

[image: Updated XML preview]

-----  EDIT2: This XML layout works! Make sure your toolbar is on the bottom of the CollapsingToolbarLayout so it gets drawn on top of the other views!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="This is a test widget" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="This is a test widget" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="This is a test widget" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="This is a test widget" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="This is a test widget" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want the parallax region to be pinned to the toolbar? Or will it just hide?

Comment: I want it to just slide under the toolbar with the parallax effect.

Comment: I posted some code that I use in my custom adapter to achieve parallax header in a recycler view

Comment: @NikoYuwono awesome, thanks for the code. I'll go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: @NikoYuwono What is interesting though, just FYI. I only get that view overlap from my edit when i cant set an elevation to the toolbar. like API < 21.

Comment: Hmmm from what I know Android Design Support library provide pin and parallax where pin will pin the the item to the tool bar and the parallax one is more appropiate for Image I think. Reference in here -> http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html
Check the collapsing toolbar section

Comment: @NikoYuwono well I just figured it out. I had to move the toolbar to the bottom of the collapsingtoolbar layout so that it is on top of the stack. I will modify my edit to reflect the working code.

Comment: @hitch.united Your solution worked. I think you've better post your own solution as an answer. That will be valuable to getting up-votes and useful for other people who seek for the same solution.

Comment: @hata you're right. I posted my solution as an answer to future readers. Thanks

Comment: @hitch.united Dose it work properly with RecyclerView? because when i scroll up in recyclerview it moves down and directly scrolls up to the toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I managed to get it to work.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="This is a test widget" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="This is a test widget" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="This is a test widget" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="This is a test widget" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="This is a test widget" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Make sure your toolbar is on the bottom of the CollapsingToolbarLayout so it gets drawn on top of the other views!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to achieve can't be done with the support library.
But you can try add this to your adapter :

```
    private CustomRelativeWrapper mHeader;

    public void setParallaxHeader(View header, RecyclerView view) {
        Context context = header.getContext();
        mRecyclerView = view;
        mHeader = new CustomRelativeWrapper(context);
        mHeader.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mHeader.addView(header, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        view.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (mHeader != null) {
                    mTotalYScrolled += dy;
                    translateHeader(mTotalYScrolled);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

where translate header is :

```
public void translateHeader(float of) {
    float ofCalculated = of * SCROLL_MULTIPLIER;
    final float left = Math
            .min(1, ((ofCalculated) / (mHeader.getHeight() * SCROLL_MULTIPLIER)));
    if (left < 0) {
        ofCalculated = 0;
    }
    mHeader.setTranslationY(ofCalculated);
    mHeader.setClipY(Math.round(ofCalculated));
    if (mParallaxScroll != null) {
        mParallaxScroll.onParallaxScroll(left, of, mHeader);
    }
}
```

and CustomRelativeWrapper :

```
static class CustomRelativeWrapper extends RelativeLayout {

    private int mOffset;
    private boolean mShouldClip;

    public CustomRelativeWrapper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.clipRect(new Rect(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom() + mOffset));
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }

    public void setClipY(int offset) {
        mOffset = offset;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```